# Flask - Can't get Facebook APP ID after changing project structure

Tags: python, facebook, flask

I am creating a Facebook app in Flask. As this is a microframework I started simple from the tutorials and had everything in 2 files: app.py and conf.py (and others like /templates).

In the basic structure (generated mostly by heroku) it was like this:

```
/game
     game.py
     conf.py
```

app.py

```
FB_APP_ID = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_APP_ID')
FB_APP_SECRET = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_SECRET')

requests = requests.session()
app_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{0}'.format(FB_APP_ID)
FB_APP_NAME = json.loads(requests.get(app_url).content).get('name')
FB_APP_LOGO = json.loads(requests.get(app_url).content).get('logo_url')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.from_object('conf.Config')


@app.route('/channel.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_channel():
    return render_template('channel.html')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index'+str(FB_APP_ID)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    print requests.headers
    if app.config.get('FB_APP_ID') and app.config.get('FB_APP_SECRET'):
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
    else:
        print 'Cannot start application without Facebook App Id and Secret set'
```

conf.py

```
import os

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = False
    LOG_LEVEL = os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG')
    FBAPI_APP_ID = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_APP_ID')
    FBAPI_APP_SECRET = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_SECRET')
    FBAPI_SCOPE = ['user_likes', 'user_photos', 'user_photo_video_tags']
```

I wanted to make it perfect MVC so I used [this link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/) and the problem started.

```
/game
    conf.py
    runserver.py
    /game
        /templates
        /static
        __init__.py
        views.py
        models.py
```

runserver.py

```
import os
from game import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
   # print requests.headers
    if app.config.get('FB_APP_ID') and app.config.get('FB_APP_SECRET'):
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
    else:
        print 'Cannot start application without Facebook App Id and Secret set'
```

__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
import os,  requests, json

SCRIPTS='static/scripts/'


FB_APP_ID = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_APP_ID')
FB_APP_SECRET = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_SECRET')

requests = requests.session()
app_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{0}'.format(FB_APP_ID)
FB_APP_NAME = json.loads(requests.get(app_url).content).get('name')
FB_APP_LOGO = json.loads(requests.get(app_url).content).get('logo_url')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.from_object('conf.Config')

import game.views
import game.models
```

conf.py stays the same and index view is in views.

THE PROBLEM: In the first structure (simple) os.environ got all the FB_APP_ID and FB_APP_SECRET just fine, and I could do with the data whatever I want.

Now (in the MVC) it just does not fetch the variables and what I have there is "None".
I have tried to put the __init__ == __main__ wherever I could but nothing really worked.

The conf.py has all the data put there in the beginning (like DEBUG=TRUE or LOG LEVEL). It's just the fb data that I don't get.

Comment: What does `os.environ` look like in both cases?

Comment: You mean what it should return?

Comment: Simple: http://speedy.sh/yZZux/simple-environ
MVC: http://speedy.sh/B55Qz/mvc-environ

I already noticed that in MVC there are no Facebook variables. I don't really know why.

What I use to emulate Facebook env is run the app locally using foreman. The app on FB is configured to use http://127.0.0.1:5000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET in your environment

Say your virtual environment is named venv

create a file called .venv in the project root (same directory that has requirements.txt, Procfile, .gitignore, etc)

add put this into the file and save:

```
FACEBOOK_APP_ID=1234...
FACEBOOK_SECRET=ABCD...
```

your FACEBOOK_APP_ID and FACEBOOK_SECRET are found by going to the basic settings of your app on developers.facebook.com